# Adding an updatable combobox

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, combobox, ttk

I am trying to create a combobox in ttk that will take output from an SQL query and put it in its drop down menu. To do this I have used postcommand in my combobox as below:

```
self.Port_Drop_Down = ttk.Combobox(EDM_DB_frm, state="readonly", postcommand=self.upd_edm_ports)
```

and then have the SQL function it is calling working like below:

```
def upd_edm_ports(self):
        portinfo_tpl = rgu.get_edm_ports("server", "database")    
        self.Port_Drop_Down["values"] = portinfo_tpl
```

The portinfo_tpl is generating a tuple looking like ("port1", "port2", ..., "portn").

But when I access the drop down nothing shows up.

Comment: That should work. Can you add `print(type(portinfo_tpl), portinfo_tpl)` in your `upd_edm_ports` method to see if it really returns something.

Comment: https://ideone.com/sY7dn7 This minimal code runs as expected. So, probably, something is wrong with the rest of your program, that you haven't showed us.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried to simplify cut out the rest of my program just leaving the problem part and it started working and as I rebuilt the program again in a simpler manner it continued working. So I don't know what was wrong but it is now working after simplifying my program.

Comment: Sorry, I think I just found what I was doing wrong I was deleting my checks and it stopped working. So after some testing realized as long as I have some copy of that function running as the initial GUI is created it works otherwise it doesn't?